# acegi ntlm how to?

Tags: java, spring, ntlm, spring-security

I have an application that using ldap acegi-security-1.0.2.jar . I able to authenticate the user with active directory. I wanted to add NTLM auto login feature for my application. May i know what extra acegi library do i need to do this?  is there any example on acegi+nltm on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Security 2 supports NTLM, if you can´t upgrade the library try [Jespa](http://www.ioplex.com/jespa.html).

Some of the things that you can do with Jespa include:

- **Implement NTLM Single Sign-On (SSO) for HTTP servers**
- Check Windows group membership
- Enable NTLM authentication with AD using a JAAS LoginModule
- **Add NTLM to the builtin HTTP stack or another HTTP client**
- Use NTLM with SASL clients and SASL servers
- Add NTLM to the standard JNDI LDAP client
- Easily authenticate and encrypt network communication
- Create advanced and custom solutions using our intuitive "security provider" API

Answer (score 0):

Here's another open source library, http://spnego.sourceforge.net, that can support integrated windows authentication/sso (no prompt).

The library is installed as a servlet filter.

Answer (score 0):

Waffle is drop in solution that can be used with springsecurity/acegi to achieve this: https://github.com/dblock/waffle

Drop in meaning not have to do all those things in the above list - but having to add a SPN.